# Album coding errors, simple PHP

Tags: php, error-handling

I'm currently trying to develop the following function:

When someone wants to see their album or profile photos, I would like to use either `album_id` or `id` in the url, like this:

```
album.php?album_id=(numeric Number)
album.php?id=(numeric number)
```

I am currently able to execute the first command and when I attempt the second, it fails to load instead I'm taken to the index page (as per the script's design.)

Here is my code:

```
$album_id = addslashes(is_numeric($HTTP_GET_VARS["album_id"]));
$profile_id = addslashes(is_numeric($HTTP_GET_VARS["id"]));
?>
<?php
if($album_id==Null||!$profile_id==Null)
{
    print("<script language='JavaScript'> window.location='index.php'; </script>");
}
  else
{
if ($album_id==$album_id)
{
    include("/home/emo/public_html/incldues/layout/photos/pages/albums/album_photos.php");
}
  else
{
if ($profile_id==$profile_id)
{
    include("/home/emo/public_html/incldues/layout/photos/pages/albums/profile_photos.php");
}
  else
{
    include("/home/emo/public_html/incldues/layout/photos/pages/albums/album_photos.php");
}
}
}
?>
```

And to clarify, those "pages" contain nothing but bold saying:
**Show album photos** and **Show user photos**

But what I can't seem to fathom as to what my problem might be.

Comment: `$HTTP_GET_VARS` is extremely deprecated. Use `$_GET['album_id']` instead

Comment: Why can't you write the codes here in text but make it an image?

Comment: @Antony - Something about it being inaccurate or not accepted. Maybe cause of the <?php> tag?

Comment: @PRPGFerret - I'll give it a whirl, i'll keep you posted.

Comment: Also, why are you testing if `$album_id == $album_id`? And the same for `$profile_id`?

Comment: @PRPGFerret - Unfortunately the $GET tag didn't make it better, although it's good to know it should still be used.

Comment: @PRPGFerret - The idea was to make it so $album_id or $profile_id (if they're NULLed) to be redirected to the main page so i wouldn't allow a hacking XSS script attack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call `album.php?album_id={id}`, `$_GET['id']` is null, making your first `if` statement return to the index page.

```
if (($album_id == null) || ($profile_id == null)) { ... }
```

One will always be `null` unless you call `album.php?album_id={aid}&id={pid}`

```
if (($album_id == null) && ($profile_id == null)) {
    # redirect to index.php
} else {
    if ($album_id != null) {
        # load album
    } else if ($profile_id != null) {
        # load profile
    } else {
        # both given, redirect to error.
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh wow haha, that solved it. Thanks mate, kinda still learning PHP but this solved the problem in a second. In fact, that && thing went under my head by a long shot.

Comment: I've been there too. The `||` tells the if statement `OR` so if either of them is `null`, it will trigger. `&&` tells the if statement `AND` so if `both` are `null`, it will trigger, else it continues.

Comment: very clever, guess i still have to hit the books with PHP. Been coding since i was 14 but damn, still a lot to learn about this. (and PHP is nothing compared to Javascript coding or any of those other advanced ones.)

Answer (score 0):

Your condition `if($album_id==$album_id)` will always be true because they both are same and the `else` part is never executed.

Comment: Very true mate, i should've foresaw the problem but it went under my head.